# How to move rectangle in the grid

Tags: c#, wpf, rectangles

the Rectangle in a table made by grid(4*4) , i want to move it by keboard up.right.left and down

```
<Rectangle Name="pic" Grid.Row=" 0" Grid.Column="0" >
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="d0c8a786c9177f3ea9ab277d70cf3bc79f3d5627.jpg"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

Comment: Show what you have tried. When nothing, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626830/move-focus-in-response-to-keyboard-events-in-xaml), where input events on the control are bound to a `CommandBinding`, in which you can write the code to move the element according to the pressed key(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean how to move a control from one Column/Row to another then use static [Grid.SetColumn Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setcolumn.aspx) and [Grid.SetRow Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setrow.aspx) in your keypress handler.

```
Grid.SetColumn(pic, newColumnNumber);
Grid.SetRow(pic, newRowNumber);
```